# Microsoft POS C# CharacterSet attribute cannot be set.

Tags: c#, .net, printing, display, opos

I installed Bixolon BCD-1000 OPOS Driver.It can print ASCII characters;however I have to print Cyrillic characters.  When I try to change CharacterSet 437(Default Charset) To 999(UNICODE), it returns error message. 
[Fault Message][1]

```
        public void DisplayStringOnPort(string line)
    {
        PosExplorer posExplorer = new PosExplorer();
        DeviceInfo receiptPrinterDevice = posExplorer.GetDevices()[0];
        var list = posExplorer.GetDevices();
        foreach(DeviceInfo x in list)
        {
            if(x.ServiceObjectName.Equals("BCD-1000"))
            {
                receiptPrinterDevice = x;

            }
        }
        LineDisplay printer = posExplorer.CreateInstance(receiptPrinterDevice) as LineDisplay;
        printer.Open();
        printer.Claim(1000);
        string str = "Кирилица";
        printer.CharacterSet = 999; // Unicode Fault Message 
        printer.DeviceEnabled = true;
        printer.DisplayTextAt(2, 1, text);
        printer.Close();
    }
```

How can i overcome this situtation?
Thanks

Comment: very nice question :P

Comment: Well, if you think that 999 is Unicode you are not able to read the documentation. Shame on you!

Answer (score 2):

The CharacterSet property can only be set to the numeric value of the value contained in the CharacterSetList property.

If the value of the CharacterSetList property does not contain 999, you can not set the CharacterSet property to 999.

Please check the specification of CharacterSetList property of Bixolon BCD-1000 OPOS Driver.

In addition, 999 is the value of ANSI character set. The value of UNICODE is 997.

And perhaps it is better to set the CharacterSet property after setting the DeviceEnabled property to true.